# iOS 6 AVAudioSession issue

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

In my application I have made [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback] to play audio in back ground and also to mute other audio play backs while playing song in my application. I am playing the audio using AVPlayer and also I have UIWebView for playing video in same Application. The issue arises when I play both video in web view and audio using AVPlayer. The music mixes in this case. Prior to iOS 6 when I rech same situation one audio pauses automatically and the mixing up does not occur. So kindly suggest some solutions.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue.  I am not receiving AVAudioSession delegate interruption calls when the video in the UIWebView starts playing, which causes the audio from the AVPlayer and the audio from the UIWebView to mix.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

> Required background modes -> App plays audio

in Info.plist.